# How to do a countdown with randomized time intervals, stopping at zero?

Tags: javascript, counter

i would like to add another counter in this code:

```
        function animateValue(id) {
      var obj = document.getElementById(id);
      var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
      var current = counter ? +counter : obj.innerHTML;
      obj.innerHTML = counter;
      setInterval(function() {
          var counter = current--;
        obj.innerHTML = counter;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', counter);
      }, 1000);
    }

function getLocalStoregaValue() {
  return localStorage.getItem('counter');
}

animateValue('value');
```

I would like it to scale once every second (as in this case) and once every 5 seconds. How can I? And then, how can I make it stop at 0? So without negative numbers. Thank you very much.

EDIT: I explained myself wrong.
I would like a single counter that drops in number from a minimum of 10 to a maximum of 20.

Example: the counter marks 50. After 15 seconds it marks 49. After 18 seconds it marks 48. After 11 seconds it marks 47. And so up to 0.
I hope I explained myself well this time :)

Comment: " and once every 5 seconds"  so, do you want the `counter ` to decrease by 2 every 5 seconds?

Comment: Hi @Valentina, you should try and keep all comments directly linked to your question or, even better, edit your question. For my part, I am still not quite sure what you want. Is it: one counter, going down every ten seconds, until it reaches zero?

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @cars10m. I've edited my first message.

Comment: What is the *rule* behind your interval times of 15s, 18s and then 11s?!? Which interval comes next?

Comment: No rule i would like it scale random

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was interrupted while posting my answer. Here now the explanation:

I left out the localStorage part of your question and concentrated on the generation of "independent countdowns" first:

```js
function cntdwn(sel,stp,intv){
 let el=document.querySelector(sel),
     n=el.textContent-stp,
     cd=setInterval(()=>{
  el.textContent=n;
  if((n-=stp)<0) clearInterval(cd);
 }, intv);
}
cntdwn('#one',1,1000) ;
setTimeout(()=>cntdwn('#two',1,3000), 12000);
```

```html
<p>first countdown:<br>step: 1, interval: 1s</p>
<p id="one">15</p>
<p>second countdown:<br>step: 1, action after: 15, 18, 21, 24 ... s (as mentioned in comment)</p>
<p id="two">50</p>
```

The `cntdwn()` function provides a scope in which individual countdowns can be set up for arbitrary DOM elements, each with their own counter (it starts with the value found in the DOM element), step-width and interval (in milliseconds).

Each countdown is generated with `let cd=setInterval(...)`. The reference `cd` can then be used to stop the countdown (in `clearInterval(cd)`), once the value of `n` is found to be below zero.

**Edit**:
Assuming you made a typo in your sequence of intervals and you *really* meant: 15, 18, 21 seconds, then the edited second countdown should be the correct solution.

I used a `setTimeout()` function to delay the action by 12 seconds, then, after the first of the regular 3 second intervals (i. e. after a total of 15 seconds) the first change occurs. The countdown then continues in 3 second intervals until it reaches zero.

**Yet another edit:**

Ok, so you want: "A countdown with random time intervals (range 10 to 20s each) that will stop at zero"

This should do it:

```js
function cntdwn(sel,int1,int2){
 let el=document.querySelector(sel),
     n=el.textContent-1,
     cd=()=>setTimeout(()=>{
  el.textContent=n;
  if(n--) cd();
 }, 1000*(int1+Math.random()*(int2-int1)));
 cd();
}
cntdwn('#one',10,20);
```

```html
<p>countdown:<br>step: 1, intervals: between 10 and 20 s</p>
<p id="one">5</p>
```

Comment: I explained myself wrong. I would like the counter to go down once after 10 seconds and once after 20. And continue until it reaches 0.

Comment: Yes this is awesome. Only the localstorage are missing :(

Answer (score 0):

If you can use ES2017, you can use an `async`hronous `function` to do it, like this:

```js
async function animateValue(id) {
      function timeout(t){
          return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t))
      }
      var obj = document.getElementById(id);
      var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
      for(let i = +counter || +obj.innerHTML || 0; i >= 0; i--){
        obj.innerHTML = i;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', i);

        await timeout((Math.random() * 10 + 10) * 1000); //Pause for 10 to 20 seconds. For an integer second value, wrap `Math.random() * 10` into a `Math.floor` call
      };
}

function getLocalStoregaValue() {
  return localStorage.getItem('counter');
}

animateValue('value').catch(console.error);
```

```html
<div id="value">50</div>
```

Try it (I commented out the `localStorage` part, as it isn't allowed in Stack Snippets):

```js
async function animateValue(id) {
      function timeout(t){
          return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, t))
      }
      var obj = document.getElementById(id);
      var counter = getLocalStoregaValue();
      for(let i = +counter || +obj.innerHTML || 0; i >= 0; i--){
        obj.innerHTML = i;
        //localStorage.setItem('counter', i);

        await timeout((Math.random() * 10 + 10) * 1000); //Pause for 10 to 20 seconds. For an integer second value, wrap `Math.random() * 10` into a `Math.floor` call
      };
}

function getLocalStoregaValue() {
  //return localStorage.getItem('counter');
}

animateValue('value').catch(console.error);
```

```html
<div id="value">50</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect.
I can't get localstorage to work though :(

Comment: @Valentina What problem/error are you experiencing? Did you use my code, or changed something? It works for me...